# Excel INDEX and MATCH SUM

Tags: excel-formula

I have two worksheets in the same Excel Workbook; the sheet named 'Raw Data' stores raw data, and I am using the other sheet to create conditional sums using following formula

{=SUM(INDEX('Raw Data'!$AE$2:$AE$82689,MATCH(A2,('Raw Data'!$AT$2:$AT$82689),0),0))}

This returns only the first value (1) and not the sum.

An equivalent =SUMIFS('Raw Data'!$AE$2:$AE$82689,'Raw Data'!$AT$2:$AT$82689,A2) returns 9548.

What mistake am I making in the INDEX version?

Comment: Match returns the first matching value only. Either switch to Aggregate, or if you have access to newer Excel FILTER()

Comment: Further to P.b’s spot-on response…  MATCH() returns the *location* of the first match.  INDEX(MATCH()), and all the various _LOOKUP() functions all return the *value* associated with the *first* match.  And if you have O365, FILTER() returns all the rows or columns that match.  It is very, very common for people to get started with the wrong mental picture, and so they start with the wrong functional approach.